# Loopless function calls on vector/matrix members in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I came into matrix world from loop world (C, etc)

I would like to call a function on each individual member of a vector/matrix, and return the resulting vector/matrix.

This is how I currently do it:

```
function retval = gauss(v, a, b, c)
  for i = 1:length(v)
    retval(i) = a*(e^(-(v(i)-b)*(v(i)-b)/(2*c*c)));
  endfor
endfunction
```

Example usage:

```
octave:47> d=[1:1000];
octave:48> mycurve=gauss(d, 1, 500, 100);
```

Now, all advice on MATLAB/Octave says: STOP whenever you catch yourself using loops and think of a better way of doing it.

Thus, my question: **Can one call a function on each member of a vector/matrix and return the result in a new vector/matrix all at once without using explicit loops?**

That is I am looking for something like this:

```
 function retval = newfun(v)
    retval = 42*(v^23); 
endfunction
```

Perhaps, it is just syntactic sugar, that is all, but still would be useful to know.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response guys! Nice to learn something new :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function should look like this:

```
function retval = gauss(v, a, b, c)
  retval = a*exp(-(v-b).^2/(2*c^2));
```

I would recommend you to read MATLAB documentation on how to vectorize the code and avoid loops:

[Code Vectorization Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html)

[Techniques for Improving Performance](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html)

Also remember that sometime code with loops can be more clear that vectorized one, and with recent introduction of JIT compiler MATLAB deals with loops pretty well.

Comment: Octave, though, still benefits greatly from vectorizing rather than looping.

Answer (score 6):

In matlab the '.' prefix on operators is element-wise operation.

Try something like this:

```
function r = newfun(v)
 r = a.*exp(-(v-b).^2./(2*c^2))
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) (and its relatives) is the usual way to do that.

But in your particular case, you can just do

```
mycurve = a*exp(-(d-b).^2/(2*c^2));
```

It's not just syntactic sugar; eliminating loops makes your code run substantially faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
function retval = newfun(v)
    retval = a*exp(-((v-b).^2)/(2*c*c));
endfunction
```