# Fast access to pixels in Octave

Tags: image, pixel, octave

I am using Octave to analyze some images. Now I use two nested for-loops to access every pixel but this is really slow.

My code is something like that:

```
for i = 1:size(im,1)
    for j = 1:size(im,2)
    p = im(i,j,1:3);
        if (classRGB(class, [p(1),p(2),p(3)]) > 0)
            ## Apply some function to that pixel here
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Is there any way to do this without the loops in Octave?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend taking a more matrix-oriented approach. MATLAB/Octave is very slow when using loops.

For example, let's say I want to create an RGB image where the pixels whose grayscale conversion values (0.3*R + 0.6*G + 0.1*B) less than or equal to 128 are set to zero:

```
# Read a 512x512 RGB image. 
# Resulting matrix size is [512  512  3]
im = imread('lena_rgb.png');

# Compute grayscale value (could be done more accurately with rgb2gray). 
# Resulting matrix size is [512 512 1] (same as [512 512])
grayval = 0.3*im(:,:,1) + 0.6*im(:,:,2) + 0.1*im(:,:,3);

# Create a bitmask of grayscale values above 128
# Contains 0 if less than or equal than 128, 1 if greater than 128
# Resulting matrix size is [512 512 1] (same as [512 512])
mask = (grayval > 128);

# Element-wise multiply the mask with the input image to get the new RGB image
# Resulting matrix size is [512  512  3]
result = im.* repmat(mask, [1 1 3]);
```

I recommend learning more about matrix manipulation, arithmetic, and addressing in [Octave](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/octave_toc.html). I included the original and result images of my example for reference.
[image: Original Image]
[image: Result Image]

Comment: [This previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2470844/448455) provides useful links for MATLAB/Octave performance improvements: [Code Vectorization Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html) and [Techniques for Improving Performance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowladge in Octave, but in other languages the fastest way is to get the pointer to byte array representing image pixels and iterate. For example some pseudo code assuming uint8 color size:

```
uint8 *ptr = getBytes(image);
foreach row{
    for each pixel{
      Red = *ptr;  ptr++;
      Green = *ptr;  ptr++;
      Blue = *prr;  ptr++;
      do something with Red, Green, Blue (or Alpha)
    } 
}
```

You must be careful to know what padding you image data type use at the end of each row.

Comment: To my knowledge this cannot be done in Octave. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You can always interface with C++ code for performance reasons.

Comment: Sorry but the project must be done in Octave. My current solution works quite well, but it is _really_ slow. I think that I have to do some code vectorization, but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what `classRGB` does. Otherwise no one can help you. If `classRGB` can be computed for a matrix of values at once, you can directly pass the matrix `im(:,:,1:3)`.

Comment: I've implemented Jaime's answer and is working great. But thanks for your interest